# Why does "No such file or directory" show up in my environment variables?

Tags: bash, classpath, environment-variables

I have set the environment variables for my system using the standard way (i.e. setting them in the ~/.bashrc). Everything compiles and working fine, but when I try to see the $CLASSPATH variable, "No such file or directory" message is shown at the end of the variable string, like this --

```
user@user-pc:/media/Data$ $CLASSPATH [press enter]
bash: .:/opt/jdk1.7.0_03/lib/tools.jar:/opt/jdk1.7.0_03/lib/dt.jar:/usr/local/lib/JMF-2.1.1e/lib/jmf.jar:/usr/local/lib/jfreechart-1.0.13/lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/lib/jfreechart-1.0.13/lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar: No such file or directory
```

any ideas? all the jar locations are correct, nothing is missing/misspelled, I did double check.

**EDIT Note:** I am setting them like this --

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_03;export JAVA_HOME
JMFHOME=/usr/local/lib/JMF-2.1.1e;export JMFHOME
JFRC_HOME=/usr/local/lib/jfreechart-1.0.13;export JFRC_HOME
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
:$JMFHOME/lib/jmf.jar:$JFRC_HOME/lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
:$JFRC_HOME/lib/jcommon- 1.0.16.jar;export CLASSPATH
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and please ignore all the "new line"s above, they are due to the markdown editor of the SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `echo $CLASSPATH` instead of just `$CLASSPATH` by itself -- the shell is interpreting
your entire `$CLASSPATH` string as a command, and not finding it.